# AWS Eventbridge rule to run twice a day Monday through Friday

Tags: amazon-web-services, cron, terraform-provider-aws, aws-event-bridge

I am trying to setup an Eventbridge rule through Terraform that would run twice a day (6AM and 8PM) Monday through Friday. However, I have not had luck doing that. Below is what I have tried so far:

`schedule_expression = cron(0 0 6,20 ? * MON-FRI *)`

I am getting this error:
**Parameter ScheduleExpression is not valid.**

Can anyone suggest what is wrong in this expression?

Comment: I don’t think AWS cron expressions support multiple specific times in one expression. You might need to create two separate rules:

```hcl
schedule_expression = "cron(0 6 ? * MON-FRI *)"  # For 6 AM
schedule_expression = "cron(0 20 ? * MON-FRI *)" # For 8 PM
```

Each `schedule_expression` should be used in a separate EventBridge rule resource in your Terraform configuration.

Comment: Hey, it does actually. I put an extra 0 in the starting of the expression. This is the right expression.

cron(0 11,01 ? * MON-FRI *)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventBridge cron expressions follow: `cron(minutes hours day-of-month month day-of-week year)`

You have too many parameters, the expression you're looking for is:

```
cron(0 6,20 ? * MON-FRI * )
```